# Merging Rows with common column

Tags: excel

How can I merge the rows with the same Date together? The merge/centre function doesn't work. Removing duplicates doesn't work either. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code which will consolidate the rows with a matching date:

```
Sub ConsolidateRows()
'takes rows and consolidate one or many cells, based on one or many cells matching with above or below rows.

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim colMatch As Variant, colConcat As Variant

'**********PARAMETERS TO UPDATE****************
Const strMatch As String = "A"    'columns that need to match for consolidation, separated by commas
Const strConcat As String = "B,C,D"     'columns that need consolidating, separated by commas
Const strSep As String = ""     'string that will separate the consolidated values
'*************END PARAMETERS*******************

application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating to avoid screen flashes

colMatch = Split(strMatch, ",")
colConcat = Split(strConcat, ",")

lastRow = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1 'loop from last Row to one

    For j = 0 To UBound(colMatch)
        If Cells(i, colMatch(j)) <> Cells(i - 1, colMatch(j)) Then GoTo nxti
    Next

    For j = 0 To UBound(colConcat)
        Cells(i - 1, colConcat(j)) = Cells(i - 1, colConcat(j)) & strSep & Cells(i, colConcat(j))
    Next

    Rows(i).Delete

nxti:
Next

application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm familiar with VBA. How I insert this code into Excel and use it?

Comment: in excel, use alt+F11 to open VBA editor, Insert\Module, copy the code, then go back to Excel and use F8 to select the code and run it.