# merge columns over multiple rows with a common column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Trying to "flatten" a Google sheet across multiple rows by using one row as the "primary key".

VBA answer in Excel: [Merging Rows with common column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380902/merging-rows-with-common-column)

Tried doing Filter with Find but I am getting mismatched row errors. Not sure how to leverage `VLOOKUP` across multiple rows with criteria of the cell value being not blank.

Before

```
| animal | legs | cute |
|--------|------|------|
| dog    |      |      |
| dog    | 4    |      |
| dog    |      | yes  |
| cat    | 4    |      |
```

After

```
| animal | legs | cute |
|--------|------|------|
| dog    | 4    | yes  |
| cat    | 4    |      |
```

Comment: Have you tried `query()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this:

```
={A1:C1; ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(TO_TEXT(A2:B), "where Col2 !=''", 0), 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A2:B), "select Col1 where Col2 !=''", 0), 
 SORT(A2:C, 3, 1), 3, 0))})}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Breaking this down.
Get column headers
Where "heads" column are not a ''" (???)
do a vlookup against any "animal" column where "heads" column is not ''" (???)
sort

Comment: it translates as: **A1:C1** for headers 1st query to get rid off the empty rows from A:B range. then simple vlookup to match the 3rd column onto A:B range (so it wouldn't be out of sync) thats the 2nd query (for vlookup we just need 1st column) and do match up against A:C where we sort the 3rd column to get all empty rows at the bottom so vlookup won't pick them up